# Math to create SVG pie chart without using CSS or JS

Tags: html, math, svg, charts, geometry

I am seeking to create a pie chart in pure SVG. I do not want to use JS or CSS, which most of the solutions on this site utilize. I came across this great article that explains how to create a pie chart in pure SVG: https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/how_to_code_an_SVG_pie_chart

The problem is that this article only describes how to make only one slice. I am seeking to create a pie chart that can contain up to a maximum of 360 elements (in which each slice of the pie will be ‭0.27‬% of it).

I have attempted to create another wedge in the following example by rotating it to -89 instead of the -90, but I'm not getting the results I'm looking for: https://codepen.io/HexylCinnamal/pen/KKwEjpK

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"/>
    <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent" stroke="tomato" stroke-width="10"
        stroke-dasharray="calc(1 * 31.4 / 100) 31.4" transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)"/>
    <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10"
        stroke-dasharray="calc(1 * 31.4 / 100) 31.4" transform="rotate(-89) translate(-20)"/>
</svg>
```

I was wondering if there is any math I need to do to calculate the proper angle and translation to make the blue wedge appear next to the red one.

Comment: Units are mandatory in calc expressions.

Comment: For those wondering about the *magic number*: `31.4` is the circumference at the stroke center, viz. `2*Math.PI*r`, where `r=5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Unfortunately, `calc()` to calculate the attribute `stroke-dasharray` only works in`Chrome`**

For a cross-browser solution, it is necessary to calculate and assign values in the stroke-dasharray.

`stroke-dasharray ="Circumference * 0.35, Circumference"` or  `stroke-dasharray = "31.4 * 0.35, 31.4"` or `stroke-dasharray="10.99 31.4"`

```html
<svg height="20%" width="20%" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="border:1px solid gray; ">
  <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="white" />
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="bisque"
          stroke="tomato"
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke-dasharray="10.99 31.4" />
</svg>
```

For two segments:

1. red="35%"
2. blue="15%"  `stroke-dasharray = 31.4 * 0.15, 31.4` or `stroke-dasharray ="4.71, 31.4"`

```html
<svg height="20%" width="20%" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="border:1px solid; ">
  <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="white" />
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="bisque"
          stroke="tomato"
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke-dasharray="10.99 31.4" />
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="bisque"
          stroke="dodgerblue"
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke-dasharray="4.71 31.4" />   
</svg>
```

We see that the blue sector overlaps the red sector; therefore, it is necessary to shift the blue sector by an amount equal to the length of the red sector `10.99`

Add to shift the blue sector `stroke-dashoffset="-10.99"`

```html
<svg height="20%" width="20%" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="border:1px solid; ">
   <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="bisque" /> 
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
          stroke="tomato"
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke-dasharray="10.99 31.4" />
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
          stroke="dodgerblue"
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke-dasharray="4.71 31.4"
    stroke-dashoffset="-10.99"
    />   
 
</svg>
```

Four sectors

**The solution works in all modern browsers including `MS Edge`**

```html
<!-- https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/how_to_code_an_SVG_pie_chart -->
<svg height="20%" width="20%" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="border:1px solid; ">
   <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="bisque" /> 
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
          stroke="tomato"
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke-dasharray="10.99 31.4" />
    
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
          stroke="dodgerblue"
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke-dasharray="4.71 31.4"
    stroke-dashoffset="-10.99"
    />   
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
          stroke="gold"
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke-dasharray="9.42 31.4"
    stroke-dashoffset="-15.7"
    />       
   <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
          stroke="yellowgreen"
          stroke-width="10"
          stroke-dasharray="6.28 31.4"
    stroke-dashoffset="-25.12"
    />   
  <text x="10" y="15" font-size="3px" fill="black" >35%</text> 
    <text x="1" y="14" font-size="3px" fill="black" >15%</text> 
     <text x="4" y="6" font-size="3px" fill="black" >30%</text> 
    <text x="12" y="8" font-size="3px" fill="black" >20%</text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will use this method instead to be more compatible. And good news, MS Edge is now going to be running the same engine as Chrome! https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge

Comment: Chrome's implementation of calc is simply wrong per the specification for calc (units are mandatory in calc expressions). If you use units properly then calc will work cross browser.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to fix your problem is using a different `viewBox`: `"-10 -10 20 20"`making the point `0,0` the center of the svg canvas. Please observe that you don't need the `cx` and `cy` attributes anymore and the transformation is only rotating.

I'm supposing that you want to divide the circle in 100 parts. In  this case you'll need to rotate the second circle -90 + 360/100 or -90 - 360/100 degs.

```css
circle{stroke-dasharray:calc(31.4 / 100) 31.4;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20">
  <circle r="10" fill="transparent"/>
  <circle r="5"  fill="transparent" stroke="tomato" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(-90)"/>
  <circle r="5"  fill="transparent" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(-86.4)"/>
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

Using  `circle{ stroke-dasharray:calc(31.4px / 100) 31.4;}` will make it a) work in Firefox b) be valid according to the w3c rules for calc as commented by Robert Longson.

```css
circle{ stroke-dasharray:calc(31.4px / 100) 31.4;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20">
  <circle r="10" fill="transparent"/>
  <circle r="5"  fill="transparent" stroke="tomato" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(-90)"/>
  <circle r="5"  fill="transparent" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" transform="rotate(-86.4)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: So if I wanted to divide the circle into 360 parts, do I only modify the rotation or is there a value that I have to change for the thickness? I have played around with the numbers, I don't see anything that will make the wedges more thin.

Comment: The rotation and the value for the stroke-dasharray for the wedges

Comment: If you edit the answer to be calc(31.4px / 100) 31.4;} your answer will a) work in Firefox b) be valid according to the w3c rules for calc